# gwt-preprocessor - Unknown argument: -remoteUI

Tags: gwt, reflection, gwt-preprocessor

I'm trying to use the gwt-preprocessor for reflection with gwt. I created a run configuration for it in Eclipse. It seems to run the preprocessor fine, but after that I think it's trying to run the gwt compiler when I get "Unknown argument: -remoteUI".

If I remove the "remoteUI" argument from the run configuration, then I get the following error: Missing required argument 'module[s]'

If someone has a working configuration in Eclipse, can you specify the exact steps for installing gwt-preprocessor?  Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote? Frankly even though i do not know the answer i am curious about gwt-preprocessor. To user2059514 - Please clean up the question with mode details and what you are trying. Note - javascript does not have concept of reflection and hence GWT blocks it out.

Comment: Thanks. Here is more info. Since the GWT compiler is a java-to-javascript compiler, it does not handle reflection. If you try to call class.getFields() you get an error stating that the method doesn't exist. What needs to happen is for the java code to be preprocessed and the reflection methods made available. That is what the gwt-preprocessor evidently does. I followed the instructions as http://code.google.com/p/gwt-preprocessor/. Evidently the org.hawk.gwt.ppc.CompilerWrapper class is a wrapper that first does preprocessing and then calls the GWT compiler.

Comment: The original main class in the run configuration was com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode. The gwt-preprocessor instructions say to change this to org.hawk.gwt.ppc.CompilerWrapper. I think the problem may be that, after preprocessng, the preprocessor is calling com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler. When I enter that as a main class I get all the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using dev mode please use `org.hawk.gwt.ppc.DevModeWrapper` instead of `org.hawk.gwt.ppc.CompilerWrapper` as main class. Here is my example how I'm creating debug configurations:

1. Create web application configuration (gwt web application).
2. On the main tab replace DevMode class with `org.hawk.gwt.ppc.DevModeWrapper`
3. Here is example of Arguments->Program arguments section:

   `-Puse-generics -Pprocess-annotations -Preflect=org.hawk.gwtppc.webtest.tests.** -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -logLevel INFO -codeServerPort 9997 -port 8888 -war /Users/alexbereznevatiy/dev/gwtppc/webtests/war org.hawk.gwtppc.webtest.webtest`
4. The rest is pretty much the same. Make sure you are including proprocessor binary to the classpath tab as well as on sources tab.

Feel free to ask any questions or register bugs in [gwt-preprocessor](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-preprocessor/)  (if you find any).